# bash Changing every other comma to point

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

I am working with set of data which is written in Swedish format. comma is used instead of point for decimal numbers in Sweden.

My data set is like this:

```
1,188,1,250,0,757,0,946,8,960

1,257,1,300,0,802,1,002,9,485

1,328,1,350,0,846,1,058,10,021

1,381,1,400,0,880,1,100,10,418
```

Which I want to change every other comma to point and have output like this:

```
1.188,1.250,0.757,0.946,8.960

1.257,1.300,0.802,1.002,9.485

1.328,1.350,0.846,1.058,10.021

1.381,1.400,0.880,1.100,10.418
```

Any idea of how to do that with simple shell scripting. It is fine If I do it in multiple steps. I mean if I change first the first instance of comma and then the third instance and ...

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 6):

Using sed

```
sed 's/,\([^,]*\(,\|$\)\)/.\1/g' file

1.188,1.250,0.757,0.946,8.960

1.257,1.300,0.802,1.002,9.485

1.328,1.350,0.846,1.058,10.021

1.381,1.400,0.880,1.100,10.418
```

Answer (score 1):

For reference, here is a possible way to achieve the conversion using `awk`:

```
awk -F, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i=i+2) {printf $i "." $(i+1); if(i<NF-2) printf FS }; printf "\n" }' file
```

The `for` loop iterates every 2 fields separated by a comma (set by the option `-F,`) and prints the current element and the next one separated by a dot.

The comma separator represented by `FS` is printed except at the end of line.

Answer (score 0):

As a Perl one-liner, using split and array manipulation:

```
perl -F, -e '@a = @b = (); while (@b = splice @F, 0, 2) {
             push @a, join ".", @b} print join ",", @a' file
```

Output:

```
1.188,1.250,0.757,0.946,8.960

1.257,1.300,0.802,1.002,9.485

1.328,1.350,0.846,1.058,10.021

1.381,1.400,0.880,1.100,10.418
```

Answer (score 0):

Many `sed` dialects allow you to specify which instance of a pattern to replace by specifying a numeric option to `s///`.

```
sed -e 's/,/./9' -e 's/,/./7' -e 's/,/./5' -e 's/,/./3' -e 's/,/./'
```

ISTR some `sed` dialects would allow you to simplify this to

```
sed 's/,/./1,2'
```

but this is not supported on my Debian.

Demo: http://ideone.com/6s2lAl